# Read lock for arrays

Tags: java, concurrency, multidimensional-array, thread-safety, scalability

I am writing an app to simulate a marketplace for books.

Consider a book called "BookA" which has the following data:

```
                       45   47  50  51  55    70  73  75  79 81

**Bookstore1 Buy Qty**  2   3   5   11  1   
**Bookstore2 Buy Qty**  1   3   5   1   10

**Bookstore1 Sell Qty**                       1   11  7   8  20
**Bookstore2 Sell Qty**                       2   5   2   5  10

                             **Data for BookA**
```

The numerical data is stored as `volatile int[][] dataStorage = new int[5][10]` where row[0] contains the price.

row[ 1] ..row[ 4 ] contain quantities available at each bookstore.
For example, row[ 1 ]col[ 0 ] indicates that at $45, Bookstore1 is willing to buy 2 copies of BookA. Similarly, row[ 4 ][ 5 ] indicates that at $70, Bookstore2 is willing to sell 2 copies.

I have about 500 books in my market and the data for each is stored in a ConcurrentHashMap:
(`ConcurrentMap<String, int[][]> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, int[][]>(500)`)

"BookA" ---->   int[][]

"Bookn" ---->   int[][]

Data from Bookstore1 and Bokstore2 arrives in two separate threads. Currently, I store the raw data objects in a blocking queue and the use a single thread ("ProcessingThread" ) to create and modify (in case of an update) the above array .

[image]

Finally, I have customers who, in a separate thread ("CustomerThread") send me orders to buy/sell books.

A typical order looks like: "Buy 3 of BookA at $50":

Upon getting the order, I do the following:

1) Check to see if the map contains the key "BookA".

2) If yes, then I clone the data (int[][]) for BookA while holding a **ReadLock** (ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock).

3) Then I iterate over the cloned data to find the price and the total qty.

My question are:

a) Can someone confirm that I don't need to synchronize the producer ("ProcessingThread"). Since dataStorage (int[][]) is only altered by the "ProcessingThread" thread. Further, since dataStorage is volatile, a "happens-before" will be established when I write to it (therefore, the "CustomerThread" will see the latest updated data).

b) Is there a better (more scalable than using a lock) way to ensure thread-safety in the "CustomerThread"? Could I get away by using AtomicIntegerArray?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing a bit of trouble here.  Your array is volatile, but the elements are not.  With only one thread modifying the elements, you are safe there.  But you have no guarantee that the element changes will be seen by the CustomerThread.  Also, even if the elements themselves *were* volatile (not easily done), the array would change in dribs and drabs and the CustomerThread is apt to see incomplete data.

The first solution would be to do a proper lock on each array.  Then the CustomerThread has to wait until the complete array is ready to go.  (Multiple CustomerThreads would get you around the problem of one book blocking action on other books, and I don't think it would make your concurrency problems worse.)

Another solution would be to replace whole arrays rather than modifying them.  The arrays become effectively immutable.  The change from one set of data to the next is instantanious, and the data is always consistent.  Now the fact that the array *reference* is volatile assures that the changes will be instantly visible to the CustomerThread, which now never has to wait for a lock.

I like the second solution, and it rather answers your question B.  (Atomics tend to be expensive.  If you can replace one lock with one atomic, you're way ahead of the game, but if you're replacing one lock with 100 atomics, or even just 10, you're behind it.)

However, I'm a bit concerned with the results of multiple orders coming in.  If there is one book left, you don't want to sell it to 5 different people.  It seems to me, from what you've written, that orders on the CustomerThread and info coming off the blocking queue into the ProcessingThread need to be carefully synchronized.  The ProcessingThread and the CustomerThread are each one thread, so they're okay individually.  But they could do something simultaneously, like drop the number of books available and order a number of books.  These two events need to happen in sequence, so we know who gets the books, and formal Java synchronized blocks strike me as the best way to do it.

But you know best what you are trying to do (I'm a bit confused about what kind of data the bookstores are putting into the queue).  Hopefully this gives you some information if it doesn't actually answer your questions.

Comment: You are absolutely correct that volatile array won't gurantee that changes will be seen by the CustomerThread. By googling, I found I will have to set the array to itself to ensure visibility (volatile write). Anyway, I decided to use a priority blocking queue to store both data and orders (orders in front). Therefore, only one thread ("ProcessingThread") will ever process the data. When an order comes, I "clone" the data for the books in a new int[][] and pass it off to a thread pool to execute the Order. –